# Struggling with `__reactFiber$` property React attaches to elements inside its virtual DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-fiber

So, I'm trying to dig out the line number responsible for a given React element in my rendered page. Assuming that React, in the process of virtualizing the DOM on render, would have metadata associated with the element, I explored that. After some digging, I located a `__reactFiber$******` property (where `******` is the session gibberish React tacks on to everything... to make life difficult for QuerySelectors? I assume?). Those look promising...

[image]

---

### Additional digging revealed the presence of a `_debugSource` property, and therein:
[image]

Hot diggity! `fileName`, `lineNumber`, AND `columnNumber`!? Score!

The only problem being, while `fileName` is unquestionably accurate, `lineNumber` and `columnNumber` both appear to be... wild hallucinations? Either pointing at wholly unrelated locations, or, at times, ones that straight-up don't exist. It's no better if I try and `fecth` the file, either. I genuinely cannot figure out how offset/adjust the position to get the values to correspond to anything even vaguely like the element definition.

They don't appear to correspond to the page's compiled source, nor to the source in DevTools... it's driving me nuts. Are they doings some kinda transform on it?

Anyone have any experience with this?